# How to reference a folder by name?

Tags: vba, outlook, compiler-errors, type-mismatch

When I try to open a non-default mail folder I'm getting

> Compile Error: Type Mismatch

It occurs at `Set oMailBox`.

```vb
Sub openSxxInbox()

Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim oMailBox As Outlook.Folder
Dim oFldr As Outlook.Folder

Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oNS = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oMailBox = "Sxx"
Set oFldr = "Inbox"

oNS.Logon 'does not do anything if Outlook is already running

Set oFolder = oNS.Folders(oMailBox).Folders(oFldr)

    If (oOutlook.ActiveExplorer Is Nothing) Then
        oFolder.Display
        Else
        Set oOutlook.ActiveExplorer = oFolder
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you may find the following line:

```
Dim oMailBox As Outlook.Folder
```

and later you are trying assign a string value which is not correct:

```
Set oMailBox = "Sxx"
Set oFldr = "Inbox"
```

There is no direct cast between folder objects and strings. You can use the [NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile; for example, obtains the default Inbox folder for the user who is currently logged on.

Note, you may find the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method helpful which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

Also you can define the object as string in the code:

```
Sub openSxxInbox()

Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim oMailBox As string
Dim oFldr As string

Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oNS = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
oMailBox = "Sxx"
oFldr = "Inbox"

oNS.Logon 'does not do anything if Outlook is already running

Set oFolder = oNS.Folders(oMailBox).Folders(oFldr)

    If (oOutlook.ActiveExplorer Is Nothing) Then
        oFolder.Display
        Else
        Set oOutlook.ActiveExplorer = oFolder
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: had to get rid of "Set" for the string objects and it worked. Thanks for pointing out the error.  `oMailBox = "Sxx"
oFldr = "Sent Items"`